How can I fix this problem? I'm getting this error whenever I tried to run my code
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
I'm doing our capstone and the deadline is near but until now I can't do it because my code won't run.
Already tried to update my Android Studio and nothing happens. Can anyone help me?

The answers are a little version-specific, but the principles are similar.

BTW - Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out the [tour], [ask], and [mre] - your questions will attract more upvotes and answers if you adhere to those guidelines.
